# Use composer packages in Azure Functions PHP custom handler

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to install composer dependencies in Azure Fucntions PHP custom handler.

With node js, the `npm install` command is run during function initialization.

What is the correct way to install dependencies using PHP custom handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `composer.phar install` on the command line in order to install the required dependencies for your project after installing composer onto your device and running it locally or manually. You can follow these [steps](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) to install the composer.

For more information, you can refer to this [BLOG](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-to-run-serverless-php-on-azure).